# Comparing an array to an array set in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to compare an array with an array set.
For example,

```
array 1 = [[1,2,3],[1,4,5]];
array 2 = [1,3,6,5,4];
```

Since the elements 1,4,5 in array 2 match with a set in array 1 it should return true.

Comment: You want to flatten array 1 and ensure that each of it's values are also in array 2?

Comment: No, I want to make sure atleast one set of array in array 1 exists in array 2.

Comment: so loop and loop

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over your array and check if the value exists in the other array.

```js
var sets = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 4, 5]
  ],
  valid = [1, 3, 6, 5, 4];

var processed = sets.map(set => set.every(val => valid.includes(val)));

console.log( processed);
```

There are ways to make this more efficient, but try this for starters.

---

Here's an example how you can check if any are true:

```
// Check if any are true
var any = processed.some(v=>v);
console.log( any );
```

Comment: should use every instead of forEach

Comment: @epascarello yes, you're right; `every` is a good candidate here.  updated, thanks!

Comment: @vol7ron, So it returns false and true J? BTW beautiful code.

Comment: Thank You. I'll check that out

Comment: @KoshVery yes, it's uncertain the desired behavior.  With all values it can be determined if any are true with `processed.some(v=>v)`, or if wanted to retrieve all the matching sets `processed.map((v,i)=>v?i:null).filter(v=>v!==null).map(i=>sets[i])`

Comment: @vol7ron, so don't you think that it's too much overhead? Two loops look more efficient.

Comment: @KoshVery if efficiency is the game, we're talking about bit masks, typed arrays and caching. I'm saying the answer provided is sufficient because the question doesn't express intention. What I meant in the comment is that the `processed` array is now flexible to cater to do anything. If the real intention is to determine if any array in `sets` returns true, then a standard for-loop would be desired so that the loop can break early as soon as one is encountered. But yes flexibility vs performance; without more information I think flexibility is typically better.

Answer (score 1):

use loop and loop. get all child array in array1, and check each child array include in array2.

```
function check(){
  var array1 = [[1,2,3],[1,4,5]];
  var array2 = [1,3,6,5,4];
  for(let arr of array1){
    let flag=true;
    for(let child of arr){
      if(array2.indexOf(child) < 0){
        flag = false;
        break;  // if one element not in array2, enter next loop.
      }
    }
    if(flag) return flag; // if got one child array elements all in array2, stop loop.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Flatten the first array (unpack the nested arrays). Then do an [intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885660/575527) of the flattened array and the second array.</s> Map through the first array, and for each each array do an [intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885660/575527) against the second array. Then filter out all arrays that are empty. If the resulting array contains something, then something matched.

```
const hasMatch = Boolean(array1.map(a => intersect(a, array2)).filter(i => i.length).length)
```

Comment: Suppose i flatten my array  1,
array 1 = 1,2,3,4,5;
And my array 2=1,3,4 ;
That would return true. 
But that wouldn't​ match any of my array set.

Comment: What i mean by an array set is
(1,2,3) and (1,4,5) are 2 sets,
If elements in my array 2 match any one of the sets, it should be true.

Comment: Thank You. I'll check that out

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array1 = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 4, 5]
];


var array2 = [1, 3, 6, 5, 4];

var isMatch = doesNestedArrayMatchArray(array1, array2);

function doesNestedArrayMatchArray(nestedArray, bigArray) {
  var atLeastOneMatch = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < nestedArray.length; i++) {
    var innerMatch = true;

    //go through each array of array1
    for (var j = 0; j < nestedArray[i].length; j++) {
      if (bigArray.indexOf(nestedArray[i][j]) == -1){
         innerMatch = false;
          break;
        }
    }

    if (innerMatch) atLeastOneMatch = true;
  }

  return atLeastOneMatch;
}

console.log(isMatch)
```

Comment: Stop iterating the nested array when innerMatch got false. It saves your time.

Comment: Thank You. I'll check that out

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `array1` and use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?v=control) on each number group and as a condition for it use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=control) with the second array for a relatively short syntax:

```js
var array1 = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 4, 5]
];
var array2 = [1, 3, 6, 5, 4];
var results = [];

array1.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
  if (item.every(x => array2.includes(x))) {
    results.push(item)
  }
});

console.log(results)
```

**Edited** : I'm pushing the results that return true to an empty array ...

Comment: thank you. but ild like to know how to access "match" outside of the function.

Comment: i can see "true" inside the console log but how to i access it else where in html?

Comment: @vaibhavshah iv'e edited the answer ... you can append the array to the document onload ...